# Start animation when swipe left or right on the imageview in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an imageview which animates when pressed, what i am looking to do is make the animation start when swipe the view! so if swipe right then animation goes right and if swipe left then animation is reversed! the code below is where i am at the moment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.red), R.drawable.red));
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.blue), R.drawable.blue));
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.green), R.drawable.green));
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.orange), R.drawable.orange));
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.pink), R.drawable.pink));
    list.add(new ItemData(getString(R.string.yellow), R.drawable.yel));


    final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, list);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);

    //my code from start
    final ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ItemData data = (ItemData) sp.getSelectedItem();
            int res = data.getImageId();  //change Integer type to int  if error exists
            myView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(res));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.fidget);
                }
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage);
            Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            a.setRepeatCount(-1);
            a.setDuration(500);
            a.setFillAfter(true);
            a.setRepeatCount(7);
            myView.startAnimation(a);

        }
    });
}
}
```

The item data class is

```
public class ItemData {

String text;
Integer imageId;
public ItemData(String text, Integer imageId){
    this.text=text;
    this.imageId=imageId;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public Integer getImageId(){
    return imageId;
}
```

}

The spinner adapter is

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemData> {

int groupid;
Activity context;
ArrayList<ItemData> list;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int groupid, int id, ArrayList<ItemData>
        list){
    super(context,id,list);
    this.list=list;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.groupid=groupid;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){
    View itemView=inflater.inflate(groupid,parent,false);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageId());
    TextView textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    textView.setText(list.get(position).getText());
    return itemView;
}

public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
        parent){
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);

}
}
```

Comment: see [FlingAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/animation/FlingAnimation.html)

Comment: So i would just change the onClick function to the fling animation?

Comment: Not sure how this would work with an imageview in the FlingAnimation

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/physics-based-animation.html

Comment: from what i read on that link the fling animation looks as though is left to right! however the animation i have already in my code is a spinning circle